# IHttpContextAccessor alternative for Background tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working with the built in DI from ASP.net-core and having following problem:

Using a **Singleton** Business Logic with **Scoped** DbContext (with UnitOfWork pattern), You need to have a Provider, to get your Services, which I found on the Internet like this (src.: http://morgwai.pl/articles/aspdi.html):

```
public class Provider<T> : IProvider<T> {

    IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public Provider(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
        contextAccessor = accessor;
    }

    public T Get() {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<T>();
    }
}
```

This is called in the BL (BLService like so:

```
private IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork {
    get {
        return UnitOfWorkProvider.Get();
    }
}
```

When using the "normal" Workflow with HttpRequests and via the Controllers, this works fine. But when using this inside of Background Services by creating your own Scope like this:

```
using (IServiceScope scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope()) {
    IBLService blService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IBLService>();

    // Here comes the Null Reference Exception,
    // because there is no HttpContext in the IHttpContextAccessor
    result = await blService.GetAndUpdateEntityAsync();
}
```

This just doesn't work. Which is obvious, because you don't have a HttpRequest. 

**FinalQuestion:**

Is there anything like the IHttpContextAccessor for Background Tasks/Services or is it just not possible?

Comment: Do you really need that BLService as singleton? Making it scoped will resolve all those issues

Comment: Yes, because otherwise I would get concurrency issues, because of multiple identical tasks.
And Yes, you are right, with scoped it works just fine (except the concurrency).

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to handle this (except what I said above).

Comment: @NightOwl888 This is Exactly the problem, I need an **alternative!** for the Provider of the Service, because there is no Http Request.

Comment: @Evk Ok, Thank You!

Comment: @NightOwl888 Referencing the XY-Problem: The "X-Problem" is the Concurrency Issue, described in acomment above.

Comment: How are you registering the background task? Are you using the [`IHostedService` interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice)?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Yes, I am using the IHostedService Interface, and also I am using the same Pattern as it comes with 2.1, the "BackgroundService".
It is registered like this:
    services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, StatusScheduler>();

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, this isn't an issue with getting access to the `DbContext` because you can do that by fixing your lifetime. As I said, this is an XY Problem - you should be asking [how to handle concurrency with 2 different instances of DbContext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency), which is the only real problem here. You are artificially creating another problem by registering your services with a lifetime that is unrealistic for your use case. There is no way around using 2 different `DbContext` instances for your hosted service & app.